# Redirect https://domain/ landingpage to http://domain/ landingpage

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl, url-rewriting

I have a domain with SSL and all referral links and other links point to the domain are using https: //domain. com

I want to use Feedjit visitor live-stat on index page only. But they do not support the https. Result is stat not working.

So now I am looking to edit htaccess so all landings on either 
https: //domain. com or https: //domain.com /index. php are all ending on 
http: //domain. com/

Only thing else I have in htaccess file current are direct www to none www
Else I put full path in login menu button so all logins go to https: //domain,com/login,php That works ok for me.

I use linux server/cpanel

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your .htaccess file at your site's root directory below your `www` to non-`www` rule.

```
# Force http:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```